# Как правильно воспроизводить звуки на iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, spritekit

Использую `SpriteKit` и все хорошо, если выключить звуки то показывает практически стабильные 60fps. Но стоит включить звуки, как начинаются неприятные просадки на 2-3-4-5 кадров во время воспроизведения звуков, которые особо ничего не портят, но при этом создают неприятные микрофризы, чувствуется что не хватает плавности.

**Собственно воспрос:** как выводить звуки на `iOS/SpriteKit` без потери fps?

Изначально я использовал для воспроизведения `SKAudioNode` без `dispatch`, и просадки были значительными, потом переделал под следующий вид:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue( DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^(void){

    SKAudioNode *newAudio = [[SKAudioNode alloc] initWithFileNamed:nameSound];
    [newAudio runAction:[SKAction changeVolumeTo:1.0 duration:0]];
    newAudio.autoplayLooped = false;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [scene addChild:newAudio];
        [newAudio runAction:[SKAction play]];
    });
});
```

После этого изменения стало намного лучше, но все равно, как выше написал, остались неприятные просадки от которых хотелось бы избавиться. Если вообще убрать воспроизведение звуков, то стабильные 60fps.

Пробовал так же воспроизводить звуки через `AVAudioPlayer`, но получалось хуже чем с `SKAudioNode`, просадки были еще больше.

Comment: У вас довольно непростой вопрос. Вы можете сделать минимальный проект, демонстрирующий просадки?

Comment: @IvanKramarchuk постараюсь позже сделать. В целом используется SpriteKit + LevelHelper 2. В данной связке LH самое требовательное звено, ибо не плохо грузит систему.

Comment: Для быстрого вывода звука надо использовать audiounit'ы  https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiounit

Comment: @Yuri Огромное спасибо.. то что надо) Ответь в нормальном виде, передам тебе 50 баллов)

Comment: @Yuri Хотя знаешь.. при использовании audiounit нельзя менять громкость звуков - или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Когда сводишь несколько каналов в один, то можно задать громкость. Например вот так: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33130362/how-to-get-the-volume-of-an-audiounit

Comment: @xXxxX молодец! Подарил баллы тому, кто не помог!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я юзаю [AVAudioPlayer](https://developer.apple.com/reference/avfoundation/avaudioplayer)

Каких-то проседаний фпс именно из-за звука пока не замечал. 
Раньше юзал `SKAction.playSoundFile...` и вот там не фпс проседал, а игра фризилась при первом воспроизведении звука из-за того что я создавал экш при каждом создании ноды. Решается простым вынесением экшна в проперти и последующем его применении к объекту.

**Через SKAction'ы**

*Property:*

```
let soundAction: SKAction = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("nameOfFile.wav", waitForCompletion: false)
```

*В методе, в котором нужно воспроизвести звук:*

```
run(soundAction)
```

**Через AVAudioPlayer:**

```
var musicPlayer: AVAudioPlayer?

let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: filename, withExtension: nil)

musicPlayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url!)

if let player = musicPlayer {
   player.numberOfLoops = -1
   player.prepareToPlay()
   player.play()
}
```

Comment: Да, примерно так и происходит с SKAction.. дал второй шанс AVAudioPlayer, и действительно, намного лучше, микро фризы пропали, почему в первый раз у меня AVAudioPlayer работал хуже и вызывал просадки FPS так и не понял.

Comment: Если ответ помог, отметьте его пожалуйста как ответ (галочкой) :)

Answer (score 1):

Для быстрого вывода звука надо использовать [audiounit](https://developer.apple.com/reference/audiounit)'ы

Comment: Ответы не должны состоять из одной ссылки. Пожалуйста, дополните ваше сообщение примером.

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/166562)

Comment: @mymedia жаль, что интерфейс сайта не позволяет отправлять очки по каммету, а Вы не достаточно внимательно прочитали их к первому посту и слабо разбираетесь в программировании аудио в iOS. Подтяните свои знания, прежде чем писать и требовать примеры.

Comment: К сожалению, ваш ответ не удолетворяет стандартам качества, принятым в сообществе Stack Overflow, вне зависимости от моих знаний по теме аудио в iOS. Пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь со [справкой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers). Более того, вся важная информация должна быть прямо во ответе, но не в комментариях. И кроме того, вы вполне можете ставить оценки любым комментариям. При наведении указателя мыши на комментарий появляются значки треугольника (для голоса за) и флажка (для тревоги).

Comment: И всё же пример кода добавить стоит.

Comment: приводить тут код не имеет смысла. Он слишком большой!

Comment: Тогда перенесите свой ответ в комментарии к вопросу. Здесь принято писать самодостаточные ответы. Либо выделите самую суть в виде минимального примера (не думаю, что для просто воспроизведения требуется гигантская обвязка).